# PyQt5, как узнать какая кнопка активировала метод?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть окно с кнопками, которые создаются динамически, их количество невозможно предсказать.

При нажатии каждая из них, активирует функцию `foo`.

Как внутри функции `foo` узнать какая кнопка её активировала? Желательно узнать надпись на кнопке.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication


def foo():
    print('button name')

prg = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
names = ['one','two','three']
for i in names:
    btn = QPushButton(i)
    btn.clicked.connect(foo)
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton(i))
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

sys.exit(prg.exec())
```

Comment: А зачем Вы создаёте по две кнопки за один проход цикла?

Comment: Там только одна создаётся: 1) создание, кнопки; 2) присвоение действия при нажатии; 3) добавление в приложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication


def foo(name):                                                   # +++ name
    print(f'button name -> {name}')

prg = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
names = ['one','two','three']

for i in names:
    btn = QPushButton(i)
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, name=i: foo(name))           # + lambda ch, name=i: foo(name)
#    layout.addWidget(QPushButton(i))                           # --- 
    layout.addWidget(btn)
    
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

sys.exit(prg.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подходит, спасибо, объясните пожалуйста что происходит в той строке с лямбдой. Например почему не задействовано "ch"?

Comment: @arachnoden  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked    ch -> checked

Comment: Есть что-то подобное для выпадающих списков? При том же условии их динамического создания

Comment: @LegendaryHunter задайте новый вопрос. Приложите пример кода, который у вас имеется и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, используйте метод `sender`, чтобы узнать кто активировал этот метод:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication


def foo():
    button = QApplication.instance().sender()
    print(button.text())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
names = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for i in names:
    btn = QPushButton(i)
    btn.clicked.connect(foo)
    layout.addWidget(btn)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

app.exec()
```

[Но нужно помнить, что если при коннекте специально указать тип подключения DirectConnection, то этот метод может не сработать](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender):

> Warning: As mentioned above, the return value of this function is not
> valid when the slot is called via a Qt::DirectConnection from a thread
> different from this object's thread. Do not use this function in this
> type of scenario.

---

Или используйте [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), чтобы сгруппировать логически кнопки и иметь возможность ловить в сигнале какая кнопка была кликнута:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication, QButtonGroup


def foo(button):
    print(button.text())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
names = ['one', 'two', 'three']

button_group = QButtonGroup()
button_group.buttonClicked.connect(foo)

for i in names:
    btn = QPushButton(i)
    button_group.addButton(btn)
    layout.addWidget(btn)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: хорошие дополнения `+`, но также надо помнить о предупреждениях указанных в документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender

Comment: @S.Nick, угу, спасибо, добавил предупреждение